# How to get the html source of a specific element with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

The page I'm looking at contains :

```
<div id='1'> <p> text 1 <h1> text 2 </h1> text 3 <p> text 4 </p> </p> </div>
```

I want to get all the text in the div, except for the text that is in the `<h>`.
(I want to get "text 1","text 3" and "text 4")
There may be a few `<h>` elements, or none at all.
And there may be a few `<p>` elements, even one inside the other, or none.

I thought to do this by getting all the html source of the div, and using a regex to remove the `<h>` elements. But selenium.get_text does not return the html, just the text (all of it!).

I know I can use `selenium.get_html_source` and then look for the element I need with a regex, but that looks like a waste since selenium knows how to find the element.

Does anyone have a better solution?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code will give you the HTML in the div element:

```
sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, browser, my_url)
html = sel.get_eval("this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById('1').innerHTML")
```

then you can use BeautifulSoup to parse it and extract what you really want.

I hope it helps

Comment: sorry, I'm new in this site...
You meant clicking on the v, right ?

Comment: No problem. Thanks. I spend some times a few weeks ago on a similar problem and I am happy to know that it fixed yours too.

Comment: And what about getting it directly from the WebDriver, for example you have `wd = webdriver.Firefox()`, and I want to get this from the `wd` object

Answer (score 4):

Use xpath. From `selenium.py`:

> Without an explicit locator prefix, Selenium uses the following default strategies:
>
> - \**dom**\ , for locators starting with "document."
> - \**xpath**\ , for locators starting with "//"
> - \**identifier**\ , otherwise

In your case, you could try

```
selenium.get_text("//div[@id='1']/descendant::*[not(self::h1)]")
```

You can learn more about xpath [here](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html).

P.S. I don't know if there's good HTML documentation available for python-selenium, but I haven't found any; on the other hand, the docstrings of the `selenium.py` file seem to constitute comprehensive documentation. So I'd suggest looking up the source to get a better understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

What about using jQuery?

**Edit:**

First you have to add the required .JS files, for that go to www.jQuery.com.

Then all you need to do is call a simple jQuery selector:

```
alert($("div#1").html());
```

Comment: I don't know jQuery. Can yo give me an example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer does not work in Python 3 at the time of writing. Instead use this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

wd = webdriver.Firefox()
wd.get(url)
return wd.execute_script('return window.document.getElementById('1').innerHTML')
```