# Python 3 + Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html

I downloaded one html-page. I need to parse one string form page, but it's behind javascripts. When i run this page in browser - all looks pretty, but in html-code i see something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function deobfuscate_html(){s007=null;s7125=6 ... #long long string
```

How can I unpack this? I want to see the pretty raw, like in browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would run the page in a web browser using Selenium (triggered and controlled in Python) - you can then gain access to the fully rendered page.

The chosen answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816232/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-specific-element-with-selenium) will show you how to get the html from a rendered page.

Comment: Python 3 is not yet supported