# How to capture *ANY* element where the user clicked with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, selenium

This is a follow up to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295335/firefox-selenium-in-python-how-to-interactively-get-an-element-html)

The idea is to get where the user clicked in a Firefox browser through a JavaScript.
Starting from the named question, the following **JavaScript** code almost does it:

```
var DocElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');for(var i = 0; i < DocElements.length; i++){DocElements[i].onclick = function clicked(MyElement){var target = (MyElement.target) ? MyElement.target : MyElement.srcElement;var e = document.createElement('a'); e.setAttribute('id','myUniqueID'); e.setAttribute('value', this); target.appendChild(e);};}
```

This script inserts a child with id "myUniqueID" in any element clicked, then the script can retrieve the clicked documents by doing the following **python** code:

```
resultss=browser.driver.find_element_by_id("myUniqueID") #This uses selenium driver engine.
resultss.find_element_by_xpath("..")  #This gets the parent node of selected one
```

The JS Code aims to pick **any** element clicked on the website, by appending itself to all the items in the html code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*')
```

But this script fails, because its not able to pick all the elements. For example, if you click in the month / gender form [in google signup page](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp),then select one month, it will pick the element that represents the selected month, but doesnt detect the first click on [the form](http://jsfiddle.net/34bN3/7/). Therefore, getElementsByTagName('*') is not picking all the elements in the website.

How can the Javascript be attached running for *ALL* the elements in a document, without exceptions?

Comment: The first link is wrong.

Comment: Apologies, its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hired a freelancer to finish the script. I was pretty close, but since im absolutely new in Javascript, it would have taken me too long to figure it out. I was needing to use 'onmousedown' instead of 'onclick' as event. The resulting script is as follows:

```
var DocElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');for(var i = 0; i < DocElements.length; i++){DocElements[i].onmousedown = function clicked(MyElement){var target = (MyElement.target) ? MyElement.target : MyElement.srcElement;var e = document.createElement('a'); e.setAttribute('id','myUniqueID'); e.setAttribute('value', this); target.appendChild(e);};}
```

I hope this is useful for someone else in the future.